# Why isn't django.contrib.auth.authenticate() working here?

Tags: python, django, authentication, debugging

I'm writing a simple (for now) Django app. I'm having trouble with authentication: I'm trying to use all of the out-of-the-box components, and both in the app itself and in tests, I can't authenticate users. So, for example, here's a test that fails:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.test import TestCase

[...]

class UserTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.testu = User(username="thename", password="thepassword", first_name="thefirstname")
        self.testu.save()

    def testAuthenticate(self):
        u = authenticate(username="thename", password="thepassword")
        self.assertEqual(u.first_name, "thefirstname")
```

I get an AttributeError:

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute "first_name".

I think this is because authenticate() is returning None (representing that there is no such user).

This fails whether or not I include the line "self.testu.save()".

I have other tests that pass, so I don't think the problem is with the test infrastructure. I can successfully create users and retrieve their information from the database.

The only mention of User in models.py is:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

I've read through a lot of documentation but can't figure out what's going on. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not create a `User` object with a password like that. The password needs to be *hashed*. Therefore, you should use the [**`.set_password(..)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.set_password):

```
class UserTestCase(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.testu = User(username="thename", first_name="thefirstname")
        self.testu.set_password("thepassword")
        self.testu.save()

    # …
```